# Open result from grep (or ack or compiler or whatever) in Visual Studio Code as search results or problems?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Newbie to vscode:

Assume I have output from running `grep` or [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com/) or `my-weird-compiler-or-linter` that I've run on the command line in a file, where each line has the standard grep/compiler output format: `file:linenumber:text` as in:

```
» ack -w root | egrep -v '(public|build)/' > file; cat file
yarn.lock:5322:is-root@2.1.0:
yarn.lock:5324:  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/is-root/-/is-root-2.1.0.tgz#809e18129cf1129644302a4f8544035d51984a9c"
yarn.lock:8244:    is-root "2.1.0"
src/apiCalls.js:11:let root = 'https://my.server/api/';
src/apiCalls.js:20:        return `${root}${name}?${usp}`;
src/apiCalls.js:44:window.setRoot = (r) => { root = r };
src/index.js:37:    ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can I load/import that file in vscode somehow and make it show as search results (or problems), so I can see the list nicely formatted and allow me to jump to the next match with a hot-key while allowing me to see how far I've gotten in the list?

I already realize that I can just open a terminal from within vscode and then `cat file`. Then I can `CTRL`-click on each result line to open e.g. `yarn.lock` on line 5322 from `yarn.lock:5322`. But that isn't really integrated with vscode and if I have 411 result lines I'll have no idea how far I got in the list after e.g. getting a cup of coffee.

I realize I can probably find something that allows me to run external grep from within vscode and see *that* output, but I already have the output and just want to load it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing this question, I discovered the answer: [Integrate with External Tools via Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher). Create `$workspace/.vscode/tasks.json` containing:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "/tmp/ack",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cat /tmp/ack",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "ack",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "message": 3
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Bingo!
Now the `/tmp/ack` file is used to hold all the grep/ack/whatever output. Run it with `CTRL+SHIFT+P`, "Tasks: Run Task" and then pick "/tmp/ack". Now the contents of `/tmp/ack` show up as problems. To clear the problems again, `echo > /tmp/ack` and repeat.

I gotta say: I'm lovin' vscode!

Comment: you can dump the grep output to the terminal and use a problem matcher, no need to store it as a file first.